# Apache Web Server 2.2 Redirect to Tomcat changing the URL in the process

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7, redirect, apache2.2

Pre-conditions:

1. SERVER lets call it X with Apache 2.2 who is accesible from
   INTERNET.
2. SERVER lets call it Y with Tomcat 7 in our internal network (no outside access)
3. We don't have control over the DNS so no option on changing anything there, all the config have to be over Apache.

What I want to do, and were Im stock in is this situation:

From Internet I can receive calls to X like "www.mydomine.com" this is ok, normal functionality.

**Now I have to transform only if they call app1 "www.mydomine.com/app1" to "sub.mydomine.com/app1"** and redirect that new URL (sub.mydomine.com) to Y to be processed.

Any idea on how to cofigure this properly?

NOTE: As Im testing this in local, I have change my host file to go to X when I call www.mydomine.com or sub.mydomine.com, but i cant manage to froward the redirection from X to Y on my virtualHost config.

Comment: Do you mind if the user sees the redirection in their address bar?  They would go to "www.example.com/app1", it would get replaced by "sub.example.com/app1" in the address bar, and then they would see the site.  Or do you want the user to always see "www.example.com/app1" ?

Comment: I need them to see always "sub.example.com/app1" even if they type "www.example.com/app1"

Comment: Great, it makes it easier.  You should use a combination of `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` to redirect from `www.mydomaine.com/app1` to `sub.mydomaine.com/app1`.  Use options `[R=301,L]`.